# Get profile problems

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I've created the FB application on sandbox mode.
I use [C# SDK](https://github.com/facebook/csharp-sdk)
i'm tring to get current user profile on server side like

```
var me = api.Get("/me");
```

for all users who used my application i got my own profile not them. Why is it happening ?
How to get current user profile for user on server side ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`me` is a special Facebook graph identifier that refers to the currently logged in and connected user. If you are logged in and triggering `var me = api.Get("/me");` then the `var me` will contain a JSONObject with your user data. If you want to get another users data you'll need to store their user ids and use them to get the information you want - you'll probably need the offline access extended permission. Assuming you have adequate permissions, you can get other user data using `var user = api.Get("/OTHER_USERS_ID");`

Comment: the problem is the currently logged user gets application's owner profile

Comment: Are the other users developers this application? Only developers can access an application in sandbox mode. Also, unless the application was authorised to view the owner users data, that data could not show up. Are you sure you're authorising and logging in users correctly and explicitly.

Comment: Yes, i am sure, others users are users with Testers, Developers, Admin roles.  When i make fb api request '/me' via Javascript SDK it works properly.

Comment: Does the same problem still occur when you take the application out of sandbox mode?

Comment: I found the problem, i copied the code from blog (http://multitiered.wordpress.com/2010/08/05/getting-started-with-the-facebook-c-sharp-sdk/) , in this code access_token puts on HttpRuntime.Cache. All users which will comes after me uses my access_token. Appreciate you for help.

Comment: I was starting to think it was something like that. You're welcome.